# Trying to add an image to my RMarkdown but getting an error

Tags: r, r-markdown

Adding this bit to my code:

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Results of Twitter Poll", out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("C:\Users\johnt\Desktop\Applied Linear Models\HW4\Twitter.png")
```
````

But getting the following error.

```
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you to try replacing `\\` with "\\" in the path.

Comment: consider the case closed!